# The app has been terminated in debugging mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

When i try to run my xamarin project in debug mode for iOS it display message "The app has been terminated". I am using visual studio 2017 on windows and for debug, i am using MacinCloud for Mac.  What setting i am doing mistakes in my Visual Studio for debugging. Below i am getting in my output window in Visual Studio.

```
 Loaded assembly: /Users/user135744/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4CAF0EF4-6D74-4DFE-868D-77521B5F3ECC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/504D0970-FEE2-496C-B5B5-CEADBFA35891/ATSDriver.iOS.app/.monotouch-64/Xamarin.iOS.dll [External]
Resolved pending breakpoint for 'UIKit.UIApplication.Main(string[], string, string)' to /Users/builder/data/lanes/5665/db807ec9/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:61 [0x00000].
Resolved pending breakpoint for 'UIKit.UIApplication.Main(string[], System.Type, System.Type)' to /Users/builder/data/lanes/5665/db807ec9/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:68 [0x00000].
Resolved pending breakpoint for 'UIKit.UIApplication.Main(string[])' to /Users/builder/data/lanes/5665/db807ec9/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:73 [0x00000].
Resolved pending breakpoint for 'UIKit.UIApplication.Main(string[], System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr)' to /Users/builder/data/lanes/5665/db807ec9/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:78 [0x00000].
Loaded assembly: /Users/user135744/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4CAF0EF4-6D74-4DFE-868D-77521B5F3ECC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/504D0970-FEE2-496C-B5B5-CEADBFA35891/ATSDriver.iOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.dll [External]
Thread started:  #2
Loaded assembly: /Users/user135744/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4CAF0EF4-6D74-4DFE-868D-77521B5F3ECC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/504D0970-FEE2-496C-B5B5-CEADBFA35891/ATSDriver.iOS.app/.monotouch-64/ATSDriver.iOS.exe
Loaded assembly: /Users/user135744/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4CAF0EF4-6D74-4DFE-868D-77521B5F3ECC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/504D0970-FEE2-496C-B5B5-CEADBFA35891/ATSDriver.iOS.app/.monotouch-64/ATSDriver.dll
Loaded assembly: /Users/user135744/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4CAF0EF4-6D74-4DFE-868D-77521B5F3ECC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/504D0970-FEE2-496C-B5B5-CEADBFA35891/ATSDriver.iOS.app/.monotouch-64/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user135744/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4CAF0EF4-6D74-4DFE-868D-77521B5F3ECC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/504D0970-FEE2-496C-B5B5-CEADBFA35891/ATSDriver.iOS.app/.monotouch-64/Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user135744/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4CAF0EF4-6D74-4DFE-868D-77521B5F3ECC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/504D0970-FEE2-496C-B5B5-CEADBFA35891/ATSDriver.iOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Runtime.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user135744/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4CAF0EF4-6D74-4DFE-868D-77521B5F3ECC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/504D0970-FEE2-496C-B5B5-CEADBFA35891/ATSDriver.iOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.ObjectModel.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user135744/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4CAF0EF4-6D74-4DFE-868D-77521B5F3ECC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/504D0970-FEE2-496C-B5B5-CEADBFA35891/ATSDriver.iOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user135744/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4CAF0EF4-6D74-4DFE-868D-77521B5F3ECC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/504D0970-FEE2-496C-B5B5-CEADBFA35891/ATSDriver.iOS.app/.monotouch-64/Mono.Security.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user135744/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4CAF0EF4-6D74-4DFE-868D-77521B5F3ECC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/504D0970-FEE2-496C-B5B5-CEADBFA35891/ATSDriver.iOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Xml.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user135744/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4CAF0EF4-6D74-4DFE-868D-77521B5F3ECC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/504D0970-FEE2-496C-B5B5-CEADBFA35891/ATSDriver.iOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user135744/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4CAF0EF4-6D74-4DFE-868D-77521B5F3ECC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/504D0970-FEE2-496C-B5B5-CEADBFA35891/ATSDriver.iOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Collections.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user135744/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4CAF0EF4-6D74-4DFE-868D-77521B5F3ECC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/504D0970-FEE2-496C-B5B5-CEADBFA35891/ATSDriver.iOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user135744/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4CAF0EF4-6D74-4DFE-868D-77521B5F3ECC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/504D0970-FEE2-496C-B5B5-CEADBFA35891/ATSDriver.iOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Threading.Tasks.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user135744/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4CAF0EF4-6D74-4DFE-868D-77521B5F3ECC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/504D0970-FEE2-496C-B5B5-CEADBFA35891/ATSDriver.iOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Threading.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user135744/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4CAF0EF4-6D74-4DFE-868D-77521B5F3ECC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/504D0970-FEE2-496C-B5B5-CEADBFA35891/ATSDriver.iOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Globalization.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user135744/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4CAF0EF4-6D74-4DFE-868D-77521B5F3ECC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/504D0970-FEE2-496C-B5B5-CEADBFA35891/ATSDriver.iOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.ComponentModel.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user135744/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4CAF0EF4-6D74-4DFE-868D-77521B5F3ECC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/504D0970-FEE2-496C-B5B5-CEADBFA35891/ATSDriver.iOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user135744/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4CAF0EF4-6D74-4DFE-868D-77521B5F3ECC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/504D0970-FEE2-496C-B5B5-CEADBFA35891/ATSDriver.iOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Reflection.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user135744/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4CAF0EF4-6D74-4DFE-868D-77521B5F3ECC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/504D0970-FEE2-496C-B5B5-CEADBFA35891/ATSDriver.iOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Linq.Expressions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user135744/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4CAF0EF4-6D74-4DFE-868D-77521B5F3ECC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/504D0970-FEE2-496C-B5B5-CEADBFA35891/ATSDriver.iOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.IO.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user135744/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4CAF0EF4-6D74-4DFE-868D-77521B5F3ECC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/504D0970-FEE2-496C-B5B5-CEADBFA35891/ATSDriver.iOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user135744/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4CAF0EF4-6D74-4DFE-868D-77521B5F3ECC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/504D0970-FEE2-496C-B5B5-CEADBFA35891/ATSDriver.iOS.app/.monotouch-64/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user135744/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4CAF0EF4-6D74-4DFE-868D-77521B5F3ECC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/504D0970-FEE2-496C-B5B5-CEADBFA35891/ATSDriver.iOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Net.Http.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user135744/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4CAF0EF4-6D74-4DFE-868D-77521B5F3ECC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/504D0970-FEE2-496C-B5B5-CEADBFA35891/ATSDriver.iOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user135744/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4CAF0EF4-6D74-4DFE-868D-77521B5F3ECC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/504D0970-FEE2-496C-B5B5-CEADBFA35891/ATSDriver.iOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user135744/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4CAF0EF4-6D74-4DFE-868D-77521B5F3ECC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/504D0970-FEE2-496C-B5B5-CEADBFA35891/ATSDriver.iOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Runtime.Extensions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user135744/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4CAF0EF4-6D74-4DFE-868D-77521B5F3ECC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/504D0970-FEE2-496C-B5B5-CEADBFA35891/ATSDriver.iOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Linq.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user135744/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4CAF0EF4-6D74-4DFE-868D-77521B5F3ECC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/504D0970-FEE2-496C-B5B5-CEADBFA35891/ATSDriver.iOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Reflection.Extensions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user135744/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4CAF0EF4-6D74-4DFE-868D-77521B5F3ECC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/504D0970-FEE2-496C-B5B5-CEADBFA35891/ATSDriver.iOS.app/.monotouch-64/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user135744/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4CAF0EF4-6D74-4DFE-868D-77521B5F3ECC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/504D0970-FEE2-496C-B5B5-CEADBFA35891/ATSDriver.iOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user135744/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4CAF0EF4-6D74-4DFE-868D-77521B5F3ECC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/504D0970-FEE2-496C-B5B5-CEADBFA35891/ATSDriver.iOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/user135744/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4CAF0EF4-6D74-4DFE-868D-77521B5F3ECC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/504D0970-FEE2-496C-B5B5-CEADBFA35891/ATSDriver.iOS.app/.monotouch-64/System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll [External]
The app has been terminated.
```

How can I debug this? Is there any way to figure out why it was terminated?

Comment: Have you tried to clean the project and rebuild? Is this happening on simulator and real device?

Comment: 1.update Nuget package.  2.delete bin and obj folders ,rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that the iPad had a newer iOS Version installed than the installed Xcode version. After upgrading Xcode and Xamarin I was able to deploy on the device.